# Autocomplete with Angularfire2 and Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Does someone know how to make an autocomplete function with Angularfire2 and Firestore please?

I mean, you have an input, and when you start to write, you make a query and you get desired results in response.

I have no idea how to do that. I had some lame attempts with query.where but it didn't go well.

For now I just get all the results on load and filter the data, but I'm really not happy with that solution.

Any help would be appreciated. Better yet, with some explanation, because I'm lost in the whole angularfire and firestore thing.

Comment: Take a look at [typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples). I have done it, works well

Comment: What does this have to do with my question please? I'm not asking for autocomplete component, I'm using material. I'm asking about the request, with angularfire2 and firestore. Am I blind? Because I don't see anything about my question in that link

Comment: This is the only weakness of the firebase. To make it work you will have to integrate with an elasticsearch service. This article could help https://medium.com/joolsoftware/extending-firebase-with-cloud-functions-elasticsearch-129fbbb951e0

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check it out. I actually did manage to make it work, but it wasn't a very user friendly solution so I reverted to my not nice but still better one for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved using Behavior subject and switch map operator.

Steps: 
1. define a behavior subject with null as initial value.
2. switchMap this behavioural subject to another observalble that actually does the data fetch from firestore.
3. Define a debounce time is needed to wait for a particular time as the user types into the Input.

refer the offical github example for angularfire2 as well. I hope this will work for you.

```
 inputFilter$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    fireStoreResult$ = inputFiler$.swithMap((inputText) => {
      afs.collection('items', ref => {
        let query : firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
        if (inputText) { query = query.where('someParameter', '==', inputText) };
        return query;
      }).valueChanges()
    })
```